WooCommerce Attribute Mapping
How to accomplish searching by Make and Model with data added as attributes? Basically I am facing this, I have a website for motorcycle parts and all the data is added as attributes so I have attribute called Make and it contains all all my Makes. I have separate attribute called models which contains all the models. I have added Filter Everything Pro to implement step by step filtering and it works as expected but some ( a lot ) of products are compatible with different brands and models so the problem here is when I filter by Make my second dropdown contains all the possible models where this brand is added and it shows not relevant models for the selected brand. What is the best approach to this? How can I create or organize my data when a user selects Yamaha to see the models of Yamaha only and not all the models for example models for Honda.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
